# How do I stop USB 3.0 hub(s) from stalling during file transfers?

Tags: windows-7, usb-3

I have a reasonably powerful PC (Core 2 Quad Q6600, 8gb DDR2) but it does not have motherboard level USB 3.0. I therefore run 2 x PCI-E USB 3.0 interface cards ([Tecknet](http://www.tecknetonline.co.uk/tecknet-usb-3-0-4-ports-pci-express-interface-usb-3-0-expansion-card-with-5v-4-pin-power-connector-for-desktops.html) ones) and connected to those is a Plugable externally powered USB 3.0 hub. My problem is that during file transfers the flash drive or external drive simply hangs and I have to cancel the copy operation, unplug the drive, re-connect it and redo the copy. I have just copied 4gb from a Lexar Jumpdrive to my NAS via Teracopy and it has taken me 4 sessions to finish it! (luckily Teracopy can skip all existing files each time)

I have tried several different drives, 3 different brands of hub but I am still getting this problem. Is it simply an issue with PCI-E USB 3.0 cards or is there something more fundamental?

Comment: is the drive compatible with usb2.0 ports? If so, try it in one of the on-board inputs. If it doesn't hang, look up problems relating to driver, or (god-forbid) inherit hardware, issues with those interface cards

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check that you have hooked up the power cable required by the card? (the little white block at the back, if you're unaware)

From the [manufacturers webpage](http://www.tecknetonline.co.uk/tecknet-usb-3-0-4-ports-pci-express-interface-usb-3-0-expansion-card-with-5v-4-pin-power-connector-for-desktops.html);

```
This PCI-E card is powered by a 5V 4 pin power connector.
Please confirm that your computer motherboard is equipped with a 5V 4 pin power connector plug before purchasing.
This is necessary to ensure sufficient power supply and smooth transfers, particularly for large data transfers from hard drive disks (3TB or above).
```

Seems like the exact issue you're having.

Comment: I have molex power connections on both of the cards

Comment: Is it possible the power is faulty? Did you try non-usb3.0 ports?

OH! What other cards do you have hooked up to pci-e slots? This may be a motherboard bandwidth issue. Are you running SLI/Crossfire?

Comment: Possibly - I will order up new Y-Splitters with a bit more length to them. No crossfire/sli just a single gfx card with its power cable plugged in

Comment: Try unplugging one of the usb3.0 cards and see if it helps. Although it talks about gfx cards (with larger bandwidth usage) [this article](http://www.tested.com/tech/457440-theoretical-vs-actual-bandwidth-pci-express-and-thunderbolt/) touches on the fact that if you use too many pci-e lanes the lanes on other slots are used up. But these usb cards are x1, so I doubt this is happening to you, but lets just make sure.

Comment: I'll be out of ideas after this :P